# Kafka Consumer Attached to partition but not consuming messages

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am new to Kafka. I have a single node Kafka broker(v 0.10.2) and a zookeeper (3.4.9). I am using new Kafka Consumer APIs. One strange thing I observed is when I am starting multiple Kafka consumers for multiple topics placed in a single group and on hitting ./kafka-consumer-groups.sh this script for the group. Few of the consumers are attached to the group but they do not consume any message. 
Below are the stats of group command.

```
    TOPIC                          PARTITION  CURRENT-OFFSET  LOG-END-OFFSET  LAG        CONSUMER-ID                                 HOST  
topic1 0          288             288             0          consumer-8-c9487cd3-573b-4c97-87c1-ddf2063ab5ae   /<serverip>          consumer-8 

topic1 1          283             283             0         consumer-8-c9487cd3-573b-4c97-87c1-ddf2063ab5ae   /<serverip>          consumer-8 

topic1 2          279             279             0         consumer-8-c9487cd3-573b-4c97-87c1-ddf2063ab5ae   /<serverip>          consumer-8 

topic2 0          -               9               -         consumer-1-b0476dc8-099c-4a62-a68c-e9dc9c0a5bed   /<serverip>          consumer-1 

topic2 1          -               2               -         consumer-1-b0476dc8-099c-4a62-a68c-e9dc9c0a5bed   /<serverip>          consumer-1 

topic3 0          450             450             0         consumer-3-63c07703-17d0-471b-8c5f-17347699f108   /<serverip>          consumer-3 

topic4                1          -               54        
    -        consumer-2-94dcc209-8377-45ce-8473-9ab0d85951c4   /<serverip>      



topic2 2          441             441             0          consumer-5-bcfffc99-5915-41f4-b3e4-970baa204c14   /<serverip>
```

So can someone help me that why for topic **topic2** partition 0 **current-offset** is showing - and **lag** is showing - but messages are still there in the server as  **LOG-END-OFFSET** is showing 9.

This is happening very frequently and restarting the consumers solves the issue temporarily.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Both current-offset and LEO for Topic1-1 are 283 instead of '-', right?

Comment: @amethystic I typed it wrongly I am talking about topic2 partition 0 and topic2 partition 1

Comment: Seems no consumer instances currently are consuming those two partitions and you should check the why.

Comment: @amethystic thanks for the reply that was my exact question. Can you tell e how to debug this kind of issues?